# Cordova iOS App is showing White Screen with Random Text after WKWebView Change

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview, cordova-ios

My Cordova iOS App is showing White Screen with some Random Text while running the application on simulator after using WKWebView. It's working fine in UIWebView.
We are using Cordova 8.0.0 and Cordova iOS 5.1.1
This is my Config.xml

```
[<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
        <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
        <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fullscreen" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="~3.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crypt-file" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker" spec="~6.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-iroot" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="^4.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^5.1.1" />][1]
```

the index.html file is not rendering.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The random text is comming from the crypt file plugin - this needs to be updated by the dev to make it work with WkWebView under iOS

Comment: I have removed the Crypt plugin then the Build is working fine.. But unfortunately I can't find find a replacement for the Crypt plugin